# Installing Make Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I typed in sudo apt install make into the Ubuntu Terminal to help make an Apache web server and the error waiting for cache lock has come up. It is held by process 1300. Any ideas?

Comment: No, process "1300" is unique to your machine and we can only guess. Please enter the error notice at the top of AU and see what similar topics come up and  check the answers. Oh and "make" is totally NOT needed to set up an apache webserver.   `sudo apt install lamp-server^` is the command to install Apache on Linux with Mysql and Php. To use python install the mysql python connector.